# Keras 2D Dense Layer for Output

Tags: conv-neural-network, keras-layer, sequential

I am playing with a model which should take a 8x8 chess board as input, encoded as a 224x224 grey image, and then output a 64x13 one-hot-encoded logistic regression = probabilities of pieces on the squares.

Now, after the Convolutional layers I don't quite know, how to proceed to get a 2D-Dense layer as a result/target.

I tried adding a Dense(64,13) as a layer to my Sequential model, but I get the error "Dense` can accept only 1 positional arguments ('units',)"

Is it even possible to train for 2D-targets?

EDIT1:
Here is the relevant part of my code, simplified:

```
# X.shape = (10000, 224, 224, 1)
# Y.shape = (10000, 64, 13)

model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(8, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(224, 224, 1)),
    Conv2D(8, (3,3), activation='relu'),

    # some more repetitive Conv + Pooling Layers here

    Flatten(),

    Dense(64,13)
])
```

> TypeError: `Dense` can accept only 1 positional arguments ('units',), but you passed the following positional arguments: [64, 13]

EDIT2: As Anand V. Singh suggested, I changed Dense(64, 13) to Dense(832), which works fine. Loss = mse.

Wouldn't it be better to use "sparse_categorical_crossentropy" as loss and 64x1 encoding (instead of 64x13) ?

Comment: First, please provide an example, including your current code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Second, it seems like overkill to use a deep model in order to predict squares on a checkerboard. If this is just a way to play with Keras and convolutional networks, then that's fine. Otherwise, there are more traditional methods that have worked for years.

Comment: Provided code example for the Sequential model I try to compile.

Answer (score 5):

In Dense you only pass the number of layers you expect as output, if you want (64x13) as output, put the layer dimension as `Dense(832)` (64x13 = 832) and then reshape later. You will also need to reshape Y so as to accurately calculate loss, which will be used for back propagation.

```
# X.shape = (10000, 224, 224, 1)
# Y.shape = (10000, 64, 13)
Y = Y.reshape(10000, 64*13)
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(8, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(224, 224, 1)),
    Conv2D(8, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    # some more repetitive Conv + Pooling Layers here
    Flatten(),
    Dense(64*13)
])
```

That should get the job done, if it doesn't post where it fails and we can proceed further.

Comment: I changed Dense(64,13) to Dense(832) and also flattened Y from 64,13 to 64*13=832. Now training with loss=mse is fine. I will reshape and apply argmax later. Do I lose performance by not being able to use logistic regression and cross-entropy loss?

Comment: @TheoH. The loss will be categorical-crossentropy to use logistic regression. Is that what you were asking for?

Comment: No. I thought that when I use Dense(64*13) I have to use loss=mse. Because I can't use logistic regression, since the classes are not separated. Is that correct?

Comment: @TheoH If I understand correctly all 832 values matter, then yes you do need to use MSE, or you can use custom loss function, but creating custom loss won't be easy, as of performance because of MSE, maybe a little bit, but I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: OK, wouldn't it be better to use "sparse_categorical_crossentropy" as loss and 64x1 encoding (instead of 64x13) ?

Comment: @TheoH. As per my understanding 64 refers to all available locations on the board, what does the 13 refer to, Also what would happen to the 13 if you convert it to 64x1, Would there be an Information loss, In short what I am trying to gather is that what are those 13 features in the second dimension?

Comment: Those 13 features are the one-hot-encoding (=classes) of the square value. There are 6 white pieces, 6 black pieces and 1 empty square type.

Answer (score 2):

A `Reshape` layer allows you to control the output shape.

```py
Flatten(),
Dense(64*13),
Reshape((64,13))#2D
```